# Using ASP.NET MVC5 OWIN Authentication Hosted on GoDaddy expires after 5 minutes

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, session-cookies, owin

I had some issues with authentication on MVC5, so to test it, I created a MVC5 project using the default template, didn't change anything.

If i run it with visual studio (debug/release), when I authenticate checking the RemindMe box, it keeps me logged in like forever. However, the same code, if I publish it, when I log in, after about 5 minutes I get logged out.

I'm using GoDaddy to host it. BTW, there is only one change i had to make. I had to set in the web.config to run in Full Trust.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="None" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <trust level="Full" />
</system.web>
```

I'm struggling to fix this. Does anyone have any clue on what could be causing that?

Comment: OWIN expiration on localhost (run it with visual studio (debug/release) defaults to a two week time out - which pretty much is forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying an explicit <machineKey> in Web.config.  For instructions on how to generate a <machineKey> element yourself, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2915218#AppendixA.  (Always generate keys yourself; never copy and paste one that you got from an online generator.)

Comment: Adding the machineKey helpted only for about 10 minutes in my case. After that, it went back to the same state where people can log on with MS credentials in my site but `AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` always returns `null` from then on. I'm in Azure using MS Authentication. It works fine in most computers I've tested, but almost everyone who tries to authenticate on this service is experiencing the same issue :(